# Request paramter value is truncated to first part when it contains spaces

Tags: jsp, whitespace, truncated, http-request-parameters

I have a strange issue with dropdown boxes in jsp/servlet. Here it is...

```
  <select name="locdropdown" onchange="javascript:change()" > 
<%
for(LocationDO locationDO : locationList){%>
<option value=<%=locationDO.getLocationName().trim()%>><%=locationDO.getLocationName().trim()%></option> 
<%} %>
</select>
```

values displayed are:

```
 BI Sholingar
 BI Mahindra City
 BI Sanand 
 Rolltec_DTA
 Aztec Auto Ltd
 BI Gurgoan
```

and here is how I try to read it in servlet.

```
String locclasses = req.getParameter("locdropdown");
System.out.println(locclasses);
```

assume I select `Aztec Auto Ltd` then expected output from servlet is same right. But output is `Aztec`. similarly, if I select BI Sanand, the actual output that comes is `BI`

Can someone help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the value.

```xml
<option value="<%=locationDO.getLocationName().trim()%>">
```

The space is namely a HTML attribute separator. A browser with a bit decent syntax highlighter would already have hinted it when you have checked the generated HTML by rightclick page > *View Source*.

```xml
<option value=Aztec Auto Ltd>
```

versus

```xml
<option value="Aztec Auto Ltd">
```

Comment: You're welcome. The `onchange="javascript:change()"` in your code makes by the way no utter sense. It's basically calling itself. Remove it. Using *scriptlets* is also [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). I'd suggest to investigate taglibs/EL.

Comment: @mahendraliya: an answer can at earliest be accepted 15 minutes after the question is been posted.

Comment: It was not letting me to accept it within few minutes. Accepted now. Actually javascript:change() is making some work for me. I have not attached the entire jsp. So you may not see the purpose.

Comment: Oh, it's your own function? I'd rename it, e.g. `changeLocation()`, you never know in the webbrowser world.

Answer (score 0):

As said by BalusC in his answer the problem is with your value assignment.

Modify your code as :

```
<select name="locdropdown" onchange="javascript:change()" > 
<%
for(LocationDO locationDO : locationList)
{%>
<option value="<%=locationDO.getLocationName().trim()%>" >
        <%=locationDO.getLocationName().trim()%>
</option> 
<%} 

%>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's right. I'm only not sure why you are repeating an already given answer.

Comment: I just posted the complete code, which can be used directly. Its just that you pointed out, but didn't provide the corrected code.. Don't mind :-)